# Forward if referrer does not match a certain value

Tags: php, html

How can I forward a visitor if the visitor does not come from a certain page? E.g. if the visitor goes from example.com/1 to example.com/2 they stays on the page, but if the visitor comes from a different page than example.com/1 the visitor is redirected to the page example.com/3. Please with php. Thank you

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service, _you_ are expected to make an initial effort here.

Comment: Ok.............